# Refreshing a QWidget

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, vtk

I've been having this issue a lot of times.

When I modify some properties of a `QWidget` after the `widget.show()`, the widget won't update. Most of the time, a mouse click or when the mouse leaves or enters the widget, the widget will be updated. However, if I leave the mouse, it won't refresh by itself.

Until now I managed to deal with this by doing :

```
widget.hide()
widget.show()
```

But this is a very dirty fix. Is there a better way to tell `python` to refresh the widget ?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried update() on a parent of the widget but it wasn't doing anything. In fact, I juste realized that update() only updates the widget but not its children. Doing and update() on this widget worked!

Comment: So if your problem is solved, mark please one answer (the best for you) as accepted (to mark this question as solved too)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To update the widget, you should `repaint()` it, but calling `repaint()` directly is not very good, so try:

```
widget.update()
```

[From doc:](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update)

> This function does not cause an immediate repaint; instead it
>   schedules a paint event for processing when Qt returns to the main
>   event loop. This permits Qt to optimize for more speed and less
>   flicker than a call to repaint() does.
>
> Calling update() several times normally results in just one
>   paintEvent() call.
>
> Qt normally erases the widget's area before the paintEvent() call. If
>   the Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent widget attribute is set, the widget is
>   responsible for painting all its pixels with an opaque color.

Answer (score 6):

Did you already try the 
 `QWidget.update()`

This function updates only the visible parts keeping the invisible parts untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Since all I needed to do was update the QLabel in the widget, I simply changed the QLabel value as

```
widget.myQlabel.setText("New text")
```